# Do web sockets still require repeated HTTP requests?

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to understand web sockets, but am currently having a hard time grasping every part of the process. On the client side, we've got the WebSocket object that opens up the connection to the server. Whenever there's new data, the server delivers it to the client, right?

That's all good, but in order for there to be new data, the server-side script has to go get it. In a chat application, I can see how this works, since the server is being fed new messages all the time. But what if the new data is, say, tweets?

In [this application](http://blog.ollieglass.com/2012/04/21/bieber-fever-meter-with-html5s-web-socket-d3-js-and-pusher/) the web page is updated once a second with new Twitter data. Does that mean that the server-side script is curling the Twitter API once a second? Seems weird considering the overhead associated with the repeated HTTP requests, and the search limits that Twitter set.

In short, I understand the browser-server connection, but I don't understand how the server gets new data unless there's a script running over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on what your application is doing and which third party APIs it interacts with.

Generally, yes. If you are interacting with a third party HTTP API you will usually still need to poll periodically. But you can keep a HTTP keep-alive connection open which should reduce latency significantly.

Some services however provide streaming APIs that you can take advantage of in this case. Twitter for example does offer such a streaming API. Tweepy, the twitter client used in the example you linked to, [supports consuming the twitter streaming API](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py). This allows you to get new tweets without polling.

In case you're wondering how this works, it sends an HTTP request and gets an infinite streaming response of newline-delimited JSON messages, which can be processed on the fly.

Other services may offer different streaming APIs. If possible, favour streaming APIs over polling, as it reduces latency and unnecessary network traffic.